# TokenMismatchException: in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 33 using Laravel

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, exception

Despite searching through Stack OverFlow and trying everything suggested during similarly posted questions, I am still struggling to get passed this Exception.

I have taken over this website, and have been tasked with getting it running on AWS.  At the moment, I am doing nothing adventurous, and have simply copied the lot to a Linux AWS VM, which is running Apache, PHP, beanstalk, Laravel, and MariaDB.

The site was set up to use the DB as the `Session` and `Cache Driver`.  I have tried changing this to `file` and `cookie` but neither make a difference.

I have ensured that `key:generate` has been run and stored in the `.env` file. I have tried all different versions of the `csrf_token` output in the form, to no avail.

I'm sorry to post yet another issue around this same problem but was hoping there were some other ideas to assist me.

A snippet from my form....

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        .......
</form>
```

Following advice from @Script47, I amended my form as such, which also sadly, doesn't work:

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        .......
</form>
```

Further Snippets:

Route -  **web.php**

```
Route::any('/signup', ['as' => 'jobseeker.signup', 'uses' => 'Jobseeker\JobseekerController@signup']);
```

Controller

```
        if ($this->request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $rules = [
                'email'    => 'email|required|unique:jobseekers,email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            ];

            $validation_messages = ['email.unique' => trans('messages.auth.email.unique.validation', ['login' => route('jobseeker.login'), 'forgot' => route('jobseeker.forgot')])];
            $validation = Validator::make($this->request->all(), $rules, $validation_messages);

            if ($validation->passes())
            {
                Unsubscriber::remove($this->request->get('email'));
                $jobseeker = Jobseeker::register($this->request->get('email'), $this->request->get('password'));
                $jobseeker->sendRegistrationNotification();
                $this->auth->login($jobseeker);
                return redirect()->route('account.details');
            }
```

The crazy thing is, this works in a live environment. But doesn't work since I took a copy of the code and re-set it up on AWS.

Comment: "VerifyCsrfToken.php" Which file is it, in the one of illuminate package, the line 33 contains only `protected $except = [];`

Comment: Yes, the illuminate package one.  But in mine line 33 is where the exception is thrown:  `throw new TokenMismatchException;`

Comment: Are you using Ajax to post the form? because there's no action

Comment: Nope @CaddyDZ. A simple POST on click of the Register button.

Comment: Where's the URL you're posting to? How does the form data reach the backend? Where's the route?

Comment: @CaddyDZ umm, very good point!  How I missed that I do not know.   Let me check.

Comment: @CaddyDZ So, it must be using Ajax, as you rightly pointed out.  Weirdly, this is all working in the Live environment, it's just the copy I made in AWS that won't work.

Comment: Post your Javascript Ajax code then

Comment: I didn't find any.  So without an `action`, is it simply not just posting to itself?  The controller code I added shows that in the same controller it's handling the POST action.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong, as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction):

> Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `csrf_field` helper to generate the token field:

So it should be:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

in your form. The meta tag is generally for AJAX requests to reference the token.

Comment: In recent versions of Laravel, there's also the `@csrf` Blade directive.

Comment: @ceejayoz yep, since 5.6.

Comment: OP's using 5.4 tho

Comment: Thanks @Script47. Sorry if I wasn't clear but I have tried this also, but that didn't work either. I have amended my form as you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes I have tried clearing `cache`, `view` and `config` but again to no avail.

Comment: @AlexFiorello can you show us all the relevant snippets (by [edit]ing your post) as it is in their current form (route definition, form, controller)?

Comment: @Script47, I have amended my question with snippets.

Answer (score 0):

right below your form tag define it :)

```
 @csrf
```

Comment: This will not work. This directive was introduced in 5.6, OP is on 5.4.

Comment: Thanks, but as @Script47 rightly pointed out, I'm having to use 5.4 and nothing seems to be working so far.